# Automatic Layout Constraints in NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm creating an NSTableView inside a NSScrollView programmatically, but when I try to set the frame to the scroll view I'm getting a constraint error.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x107d4ec50 h=--& v=--& V:[NSScrollView:0x10068c570(372.5)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x107d4d020 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSClipView:0x10068d7f0]-(673)-|   (Names: '|':NSScrollView:0x10068c570 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x107d4cfc0 h=-&- v=-&- V:|-(2)-[NSClipView:0x10068d7f0]   (Names: '|':NSScrollView:0x10068c570 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x107d4d020 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSClipView:0x10068d7f0]-(673)-|   (Names: '|':NSScrollView:0x10068c570 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

It seems like they are being created automatically.

This is my creation code (using arc) I'm subclassing NSView

```
-(void)addColumnsToTable{
    NSTableColumn *col = [[NSTableColumn alloc]initWithIdentifier:@"priority"];
    [col.headerCell setStringValue:@"priority"];
    [col setWidth:10];
    [col setMinWidth:1];
    [col setMaxWidth:10];
    [self.tableView addTableColumn:col];

   // col = [[NSTableColumn alloc]initWithIdentifier:@"name"];
   // [self.tableView addTableColumn:col];   
}


-(void)createTable{
    NSTableView *tableView = [[NSTableView alloc]initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

    [tableView setDelegate:self];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];

    NSScrollView *scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [scrollView setBorderType:NSGrooveBorder];

    [self addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView setDocumentView:tableView];
    [scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
    [scrollView setAutohidesScrollers:YES];


    self.tableView = tableView;
    self.scrollView = scrollView;

    [self addColumnsToTable];

}
```

Here is where it is breaking:

```
-(void)setFrame:(NSRect)frameRect{
    [super setFrame:frameRect];
    [self.scrollView setFrame:self.bounds];

}
```

Is there a way to turn off these automatic constraints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it, the problem is that automatic constraints are being created based on the view's automatic resize mask. To deactivate this behaviour:

```
[scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

where scrollView is a subview of NSView

Answer (score 0):

I also got the exact same problem when setting the `frame` of an `NSScrollView`, within the `DrawRect` method of a `NSView` subclass.  The above solution of setting the `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO gets rid of the exception.  But in my situation, I have a dynamic window.  Indeed, my `tableview` didn’t follow the new frame size I am calculating and setting up to the `NSScrollView` anymore.

Working around for a while, I finally came up with the right solution.  It appear that the problem was not about the `NSScrollView` autoresizing setup, but setting up the `AutoresizesSubviews` of my `NSView` subclass is the right solution for an dynamic custom view.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{

[super awakeFromNib];   
[self setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];   // <- Here is the solution

    // …
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{

[super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // From DirtyRect (dimensions of the my subclass NSView)
    // Calculate the rectangle allowable for MyScrollView
    // and setting local NSRect mRect..

    [MyScrollView setFrame:mRect];      // no more ‘exception’ here
}
```

I also have to create other `NSView` subclass programmatically, which also had `NSScrollView` and `frame` setting needs.  Since those objects have no `awakeFromNib` method… simply set it elsewhere… like in an Init method of the `NSView` subclass.

```
- (id)init:(NSInteger)aSpecialTag
{

[self setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];   // <- Here is the solution

    _mTag = aSpecialTag;

    // …
}
```